# app screen is bigger than view on Android and WP

Tags: android, cordova, windows-phone, phonegap-build, phonegap-desktop-app

I am creating an App with Phonegap Desktop App and sometimes using Phonegap Build and I noticed that my site is correctly as big as my display.

**Problem:** The different devices have for example a status bar (clock, battery-status, etc.) and for example my Nexus has even a bottom bar with controlling buttons that are displayed over my Application. My (with css position:fixed) navbars are scrolling under these device-native-bars.

Any idea how to refuse this or subtract these bars? I can even see this if I have **NO** costum styles or styling libraries included.

### HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1,
    maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, 
    height=viewport-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

    <title>Streetreporter</title>
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="libs/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body >        
      TO DO content  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### CONFIG.xml ## shortend

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- config.xml reference: https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml -->
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "app.streetreporter"
        version   = "0.1.0">

    <name>Streetreporter+Camera API Test</name>

    <description>
        Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>

    <author href="http://phonegap.com" email="support@phonegap.com">
        PhoneGap Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html"/>
    <preference name="permissions"                value="none"/>

    <preference name="orientation"                value="default" />        
    <preference name="target-device"              value="universal" />     
    <preference name="fullscreen"                 value="true" />          
    <preference name="webviewbounce"              value="true" />          
    <preference name="prerendered-icon"           value="true" />       
    <preference name="stay-in-webview"            value="true" />        
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle"         value="black-opaque" />   
    <preference name="detect-data-types"          value="true" />         
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend"            value="false" />        
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />          
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen"    value="true" />          
    <preference name="disable-cursor"             value="false" />          
    <preference name="android-installLocation"    value="auto" />           

</widget>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid this problem dont use fullscreen mode:

```
<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
```

Comment: Did work for my given example on the Nexus. Not on my Windows Phone. Weirdly I can scroll downward for the height of my status/notification-bar then it sticks there. Half overlapped by the bar.

It does however not work if I use a navigation fixed to the top or a footer fixed to the bottom

Comment: Okay, when I changed my meta-tag to the following 
    `<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" />` and used your suggestion it worked. Hope it stays like this.

Answer (score 3):

First, I have not come across something like that, this might be only about nexus?

Seems like the problem is only about the height of the viewport, in your viewport config;

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1,
maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, 
height=viewport-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

There is `height=viewport-height` config, and I usually do not use the height parameter, the problem might be that, try to remove and see if there is any changes.

---

Also if this won't solve your issue, and if you want to place fixed navigation at the very bottom or top of your screen, you might do something like this.

Take your content into a carrier div;

```
<div id="carrier">
  <!--your code-->
</div>
```

In Javascript;

```
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById("carrier").height = window.innerHeight;
}
```

Here we set the carrier div's height into the innerHeight of the display screen, keep it in mind the innerHeight and outerHeight has a difference btween them so, this might be your problem when your navigation gets under your outher screen view navigation on the Nexus.

[image]

Also In  CSS,

```
#carrier { position:relative; overflow:scroll; }
.yourNavElem { position:absolute; bottom:0px; left:0px;}
```

And use position absolute for your navigation elements into your carrier element.

I'm not sure if it does the trick but, keep me updated.

Comment: On my Nexus it worked when I applied the window.innerHeight to my body. All my meta tags are still included. I did use some styling though.
`body {
          overflow: hidden;
          width: 100%;
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
      }`
On my Windows Phone it didn't work. It still is scrollable for the height of that status/notification-bar.

Comment: But it crashed after I tried to add a fixed element

Comment: Why do you have absolute position for your body element?

Comment: 'Cause it did'nt work when I didn't have it. When I used @Breixo 's solution above it worked without the css